# Printing/Accessing specific columns of a matrix, as a matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to access a matrix and print/modify only a few columns of it. Please think of it as writing down a 3x5 matrix *A* on paper, and copying down *A* without the 2nd column to get a 3x4 matrix *B*.

To reiterate, I want to read a matrix from file such as this:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5] 
 [6 7 8 9 10]
 [11 12 13 14 15]]
```

And print into a text file, like this:

```
1    3   4   5  
6    8   9  10  
11  13  14  15
```

I have used `numpy.loadtxt` to load a matrix *A*. Then, I am able to save to file just the first *n* columns by using the following:
`numpy.savetxt(fil_buffer, A[0:-1,0:n], format, delimiter, newline)` as described on this [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).

Unable to do the same if I want to print, say, only the *p*-th column appended and *m*-th to *n*-th columns.

Question: Is there a general method to carry out such procedures in python?

Comment: Try: a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14,15]])
You can then select certain columns like so:
a[:,[0,1,2,4]]

Comment: This worked, @Yorian. Converted my matrix _A_ to an array like this `array = numpy.array(A)` and was able to make a new matrix _B_ in the way that you have suggested. Thanks!